# C# to VB .NET IntPtr conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

i would like to convert following code from C# to VB .NET. I hope somebody have solution.

```
IntPtr[] buffer = new IntPtr[5];

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  buffer[i] = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100);                        
}    

for (Int32 i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer[i]);                
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try the online converter.

Comment: No One, thank you also for answer, i am not using VB .NET so frequently need it sometimes to make eqivivalent C++ code to C#, VB .NET. Usually i am not having problem with converting but this time i bite the dust at this one. Thank you again for the tip!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim buffer As IntPtr() = New IntPtr(4) {}

For i As Int32 = 0 To 4
    buffer(i) = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100)
Next

For i As Int32 = 0 To 4
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer(i))
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Aishvarya, it worked, i will accept answer in couple of minutes when it gives me possibilty to do it.